# sqlalchemy onupdate inconsistent behavior for Query.update()

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm implementing a restful POST API with Flask, using sqlalchemy to update resource in PostgreSQL, say MyResource:

```
class MyResource(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'my_resource'

    res_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    <other columns>
    time_updated = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), onupdate=datetime.now(timezone.utc))
```

There's a `MyResource` instance derived from API's request payload, let's call it `input_instance`. Below is my approach for updating the resource:

```
input_instance_dict = input_instance.__dict__
input_instance_dict.pop('_sa_instance_state', None)  # this extra meta field will cause error in update().
update_count = MyResource.query.filter(MyResource.res_id == input_instance.res_id).update(input_instance_dict)
db.session.commit()
```

With above, columns are updated except `time_updated`, which remains null; I expect it to be updated with current date time.

If I remove the `time_updated` field from input prior to calling Query.update(),

```
input_instance_dict.pop('time_updated', None)
```

then the null value in `time_updated` column will be updated with current date time, BUT... on subsequent updates, this column's value remains the same old value.

My doubt is that, even with `time_updated` field removed from input dict, `onupdate` only takes effect for first update but not afterwards. Why? Thanks.

**--- Update 12/23 10:56am GMT+8**

Additional observation, I just re-triggered the same update as last night's twice, `time_updated` column is getting updated for first retry but not the second ones. Which means, After the very first update, `onupdate` takes effect on and off for following updates. I can't figure out the pattern, when it'll work and when it won't.

Comment: I am not sure if this will help, but try adding `synchronize_session=False` as a parameter to your update.

Comment: @SamHollenbach I just tried your suggestion, the same outcome. I also tried 'fetch' for this param but result is the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar problem is also observed for the other timestamp field to be populated with `default`, say... a record was inserted yesterday, but all records inserted today end up having the same `time_created` value as yesterday's value.

```
time_created = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), nullable=False, default=datetime.now(timezone.utc))
```

After changing the argument (for `default` and `onupdate`), replacing the python `datetime` function with `sqlalchemy.func.now()` resolves the weird behaviour.

```
time_created = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), nullable=False, default=func.now())
time_updated = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), onupdate=func.now())
```

I'm not sure why the behaviour difference, there are many tutorials that using datetime function as argument, I wonder if those programs having the same problem.